How to quickly multiply 2 rectangular Toeplitz matrices in $\pmod 2$?
Assume I have an $m \times n$ Toeplitz matrix made up of ones and zeros, i.e. binary.
I then want to multiply it by another binary matrix (not Toeplitz).   If $m$ and $n$ were cleanly divisible by 8, is there a way to reduce the number of discrete multiplications by converting both matrices to bytes instead of bits? I ask as $m$ and $n$ might be as large as 256 or 512 and I'm looking for a speedup.

Is it a bit matrix, e.g. are you working mod 2, or is it a real number matrix?

@DanielV Yes, mod 2.

So you want to multiply 2 toeplitz matrices in mod 2 .

This might be a better question for the cs stackexchange, it is basically an algorithm question.  I expect there's probably a fast way to do it using a sliding window or a segment tree.

@DanielV So I can't just group 8 cells together, call it a byte and perform the multiplication mod 256?

Well if you only care about overhead, and not asymptotic speed, you can just calculate (row_a bitwise-and row_b).pop_count() in 64 bit chunks for a fast O(n^3) solution.  But I expect there is at least an O(n^2 log n ) solution to this.

In other words, since these are symmetric matrices, instead of calculating $M_{a,b} = \text{row}a \text{ dot product } \text{column_b}$, you can do $M{a,b} = \text{row}_a \text{ dot product } \text{row_b}$ .  And dot product mod 2 can be calculated as (int_a & int_b).pop_count() & 1 .

Here's a way to do it using a sliding window.
$$M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
c & d & e & f & g \\
b & c & d & e & f \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
v & u \\
w & v \\
x & w \\
y & x \\
z & y \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$R = M_1M_2$$
Both of these matrices can be encoded as
$$V_1 = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c & d & e & f & g \end{bmatrix}$$
$$V_2 = \begin{bmatrix} u & v & w & x & y & z \end{bmatrix}$$
Then look at the pairs
Pair               Bitwise And
  a b c d e f g    0 av bw cx dy ez 0 0
u v w x y z

a b c d e f g      au bv cw dx ey fz 0
u v w x y z
 
a b c d e f g      0 bu cv dw ex fy gz
  u v w x y z

a b c d e f g      0 0 cu dv e w fx gy 0
    u v w x y z

Then $R_{3,2} = au + bv + cw + dx + ey$, which can be summed from the 3rd pair.  And $R_{2, 1} = bv + cw + dx + ey + fz = R_{3, 2} - au + fz$.  So for each pair, you can just use a sliding window to calculate all the respective sums.
There's probably a faster way to do this, but it is a whole lot faster (and less memory) than direct matrix multiplication.
